# marker in my location?

Tags: android, google-maps

Please help me, how can I set a marker in current location?
Below my code onCreate, addMarker and createMapView.

onCreate
    public class MapActivity extends Activity {

```
GoogleMap googleMap;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    createMapView();
    addMarker();

}
```

addMarker

```
private void addMarker() {
    if (null != googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Marker")
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .draggable(true));
    }
}
```

createMapView

```
private void createMapView() {
    try {
        if (null == googleMap) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();


            if (null == googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("mapApp", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have shown the code, what's an issue?

Comment: how i set current location?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your marker at (0, 0)
`.position(new LatLng(0, 0))`

You can get the latest position in [onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)).

Get the latitude and longitude:
`new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())`

Use the LatLng object to set your marker.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `latitude` and `longitude` location from `FusedLocationApi` as `GoogleApiClient.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()` and then call `addMarker` using these lat/longs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get current latlng of your position 
and create latlng object based on it , and when you get latlng successfully
use this method

```
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
               Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
               String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                fromPosition = new LatLng(latti, longi);



googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.orangedoticon)).title("helo0o0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get your `lat` and `lng` of your current location and put this code.

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
            .title("Hello world"));
    }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker